# mySQL : Sum up a column of results for each day which has full 96 records

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum, aggregate-functions

I have this table

```
_date,
_hour (0-23), 
_period (1-96, for each 15 mins of the day), 
_id(of the reader), 
_reading, 
_maxCapacity
```

This is a part of a table, in mine i have over a million rows, _hour always goes from 0 to 23, but _period from 1 up to 96. Each _id has _hour and _period, but i have to delete those _id which don't have full 96 (from 1 to 96 _period for 1 day). Then with this result I have to sum _reading grouped by day and  sum of all _maximumCapacity for each _id in a day. so 1.8 _maximumCapacity value will be taken only ones for the _id in the table for 2014-11-06 NOT 96 times.

[image]

I have to `sum '_reading'` column for each day and `_maximumCapacity` for each day and `unique _id`, also this calculations has to be done only for the `_id` where `_period` has all `96 readings`.

How can I go about it?

I tried to use `sum(_reading)` and `group by date` which gives me a good sum for the `_reading` but when I do `sum(_maximumCapacity)` and `group by _date and _id` the `sum` is off.

SELECT _date, sum(_reading), sum(_maximumCapacity) from final_2014
group by _date, _id;

Also I don't know how to eliminate `readings` from the `readers` which don't have full `96 _period`.

Comment: What do you mean 96 reading and how does actually it work? Could you please specify a little bit more?

Comment: please add your code here...please add whatever you have done and what you wanted..

Comment: @ AT-2016 in the column "_period" there are int 1-96 (1 represent 15mins of the day, 96 in total) some of the "_id" have less than 96 in one day, for example, 70 on the 1st January and 96 on the 2nd January. I need to eliminate all of the data for those 70 readings so they won't be in the sum.

Comment: @Avishek SELECT _date, sum(_reading), sum(_maximumCapacity), (sum(_reading) / sum(_maximumCapacity)) from final_2014
group by _date, _id; but it groups both columns by _date and _id where as I need sum of _reading for all 96 _period for the whole day and sum of _maximumCapacity for a day but for distinct _id.

Comment: @Lina try to wright the query by own and post the expected result with your answer. The sql may not be the correct one, but it will help us to understand your problem. Thanks.

Comment: @AT-2016 could you look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38721292/mysql-sum-by-a-different-group-by 

i've simplified this one, hope it helps to understand.

Comment: @Avishek  could you look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38721292/mysql-sum-by-a-different-group-by 

i've simplified this one, hope it helps to understand.