# mySQL: sum by a different group-by

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a table:
(Edited with x5)

```
_date(2014-03-05;2014-04-05)
_period(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2; 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5)
_id(x1,x1,x1,x1,x1,x2,x2,x2,x2,x2,x3,x3;x4,x4,x4,x4,x4,x5,x5,x5,x5,x5)
_reading(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,5,6;1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1)
_reading2 (5,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,4,7,7;1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
```

[image of the table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjv8x.png)

i need a result like below which eliminates all data which doesn't have full period 1 to 5 for the _id, then calculates the sum of _reading for a day and sum of _reading2 for each distinct _id for a day:

```
_date(2014-03-05;2014-04-05)
sum_reading(15;11)
sum_reading2 (9;2)
```

[image of the table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiNbk.png)

Comment: I'm not understanding the table format very well.  I'm also having trouble seeing where the 9 comes from on sum_reading2.  I think the 15 on sum_Reading comes from the sum of the 1's and 2's and not 5,6 because 5,6 equate to 1,2 on period which is a partial and therefore not desired.  But this isn't standard data layout.  I've seen before.  Can we put the data in a tabular format with column headers and rows representing the actual data and expected results?

Comment: @xQbert, I've added images of the tables, hope this helps. 9 comes from adding 5 + 4 from _reading2 as _reading2 has the same value for the _id for a day, it just repeats for each _period, I need to take only one into calculation.

Comment: But reading 1 has 1 for all the values so but yet we sum those? if so my point is we are actually summing reading 1, but we're summing DISTINCT values in reading 2... so perhaps just sum (Distinct reading2)?

Comment: @xQbert Yes, i tried it but if I add another _id x5 and the _reading2 is 1 then it doesn't sum it up as there is already 1 for the x4

Answer (score 0):

Tested: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a3a6b/3/0)

I use a subquery to eliminate the _IDs which don't have a full 5 periods.
I then use the group by date and _ID and sum vs sum distinct to get the sum total vs summing distinct values.

```
SELECT A._date, sum(_Reading) as _Reading, 
              sum(Distinct _Reading2) as _Reading2
FROM table A
INNER JOIN (SELECT _ID, _date
            FROM table 
            GROUP BY _ID, _date
            HAVING count(_Period) = 5) B
 on A._ID = B._ID
and A._Date = B._Date
GROUP BY A._Date
```

This still may not meet your needs because order of readings and a reduction may actually be important in reading 2; not just summing distinct.  But as I'm unclear as to the requirements, and this matches the desired result... it's the best I can for now.

Update for X5 - By getting the sum in a distinct at the inner level we can then sum the readings which I think may address the issue.

```
SELECT A._date, sum(_Reading) as _Reading, 
              sum(B.I_reading2) as _Reading2
FROM table A
INNER JOIN (SELECT _ID, _date, Sum(Distinct _Reading2) as I_Reading2
            FROM table 
            GROUP BY _ID, _date
            HAVING count(_Period) = 5) B
 on A._ID = B._ID
and A._Date = B._Date
GROUP BY A._Date
```

Comment: Thanks, that solves part of my problem. However, when I add x5 as _id and have 1 for the _reading2 in the result I get 1 for the sum of the _reading2 whereas I should get 2. I believe it's because of the distinct, is it possible to replace it with the compare of the sort?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b5f6/1

Comment: Can you adjust the linked fiddle and re-link to show the problem  I'm not sure as to the date you're on, nor where the x5 is being added and with what values.

Comment: I just added : Insert into foo values('2014-03-06', 1, 'x5',1,1); Insert into foo values('2014-03-06', 2, 'x5',1,1); Insert into foo values('2014-03-06', 3, 'x5',2,1); Insert into foo values('2014-03-06', 4, 'x5',2,1); Insert into foo values('2014-03-06', 5, 'x5',1,1); sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b5f6/1/0

Comment: SQL Fiddle isn't working on me so I can't test.  But I've added an adjustment which may address the issue

Comment: it gives me syntax error for the : INNER JOIN (SELECT _ID, _date, Sum(Distinct _Reading2) as I_Reading2